# Finding 18th century birth record when "born Foreign Parts" according to 1841 England Census?

Tags: birth-records, 18th-century, birthplace

I am seeking birth and or baptism records for my 5x ggf John Kennick:

- born abt 1776 (born Foreign Parts re: England 1841 census),
- death 1848 Greenwich,
- 1st wife seems to be Mary Kennick nee Philips b.1783, married 1796 Liverpool, death 1815 Rotherhithe.

---

First wife seems to be Mary Phillips who married 1796 to John Kennick in Liverpool or seems to be the only record found for a John Kennick marrying a Mary (1783-1815)... Mary Kennick's 1815 death in *Rotherhithe, Surrey, England

---

Marriage: 6 Aug 1796 St Anne Richmond, Liverpool, Lancashire, England John Kenrick - (X), Mariner of the Parish of Liverpool Mary Philips - Widow of the same place Witness: Elizabeth Saint; Thos. Hulker Married by Licence by: Harry Housman Minister Notes: [Bride signed her surname] Phillips Register: Marriages 1789 - 1797, Page 181, Entry 2481 Source: LDS Film 1656149

Comment: I'm assuming his age was 65 in the 1841 census? Remember that adult ages were rounded to the nearest 5 years in 1841, so you need to extend your search range. Was any additional information recorded on the marriage or death certificates?

Comment: Thanks for reply First wife seems to be Mary Phillips who married 1796 to John Kennick in Liverpool or seems to be the only record found for a John Kennick marrying a Mary (1783-1815)... Mary Kennick's 1815 death in *Rotherhithe, Surrey, England (*area of everything ships and sea on shores of London's River Thames where The Mayflower Ship set sail 1620 to The New World)

Comment: Marriage: 6 Aug 1796 St Anne Richmond, Liverpool, Lancashire, England 
John Kenrick - (X), Mariner of the Parish of Liverpool 
Mary Philips - Widow of the same place 
Witness: Elizabeth Saint; Thos. Hulker
Married by Licence by: Harry Housman Minister
Notes: [Bride signed her surname] Phillips
Register: Marriages 1789 - 1797, Page 181, Entry 2481
Source: LDS Film 1656149

Comment: It's always better to edit the question to include the information there. Comments are ephemeral, so content can be lost.

Answer (score 3):

If he was a mariner, as stated in the parish register, then I'd check to muster books for the port of Liverpool. Now, most don't have names for crew members (they're not nearly as useful as the crew lists after 1835), but some do and that might help you trace his origins (although I've yet to see one with place of birth, I'm told they do exist!).

The bad news is that they are not available online, and there is no index to names in the muster lists. They also only survive for a few ports.

The good news is that Liverpool is one of those ports and that the records are held at the National archives in Kew.

The muster books for 1796 are in series **BT 98/56**. Those for 1797 are in **BT 98/57**.

---

There is a useful guide to [Crew lists and agreements and log books of merchant ships 1747-1860](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/crew-lists-agreements-log-books-merchant-ships-1747-1860/) on the National archives website.

You'll find more detail in [Records of Merchant Shipping and Seamen](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YfEDAAAACAAJ), by Kevin Smith, Christopher T Watts and Michael J Watts.